# Undefined Control Sequence with tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have created two tables and I get for both the error "undefined control sequence". I don't know, what else I could check . Here is the code of the two tables:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{.3\linewidth}
                                     >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{.45\linewidth}
                                     >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
             \toprule
             \multicolumn{1}{c}{a} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{b} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{c}  \\
             \midrule
             Auch gibt es niemanden, der den Schmerz an sich liebt, sucht oder wünscht, nur, weil er Schmerz ist, es sei denn, es kommt zu zufälligen Umständen, in denen Mühen und Schmerz ihm große Freude bereiten können. & Um ein triviales Beispiel zu nehmen, wer von uns unterzieht sich je anstrengender körperlicher Betätigung, außer um Vorteile daraus zu ziehen? Aber wer hat irgend ein Recht, einen Menschen zu tadeln, der die Entscheidung trifft, eine Freude zu genießen, die keine unangenehmen Folgen hat, oder einen, der Schmerz vermeidet, welcher keine daraus resultierende Freude nach sich zieht? & Um ein triviales Beispiel zu nehmen, wer von uns unterzieht sich je anstrengender körperlicher Betätigung, außer um Vorteile daraus zu ziehen? \\
             \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}

        \begin{tabularx}{85mm}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X
                               >{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash}X
                               >{\Centering\arraybackslash}X
                               >{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash}X}
            a & b & c & d \\
            aqsdasfhajklhjkhgawekjahwkejf & aslhafjkhsd & asfklsfl & asfhwljkf
        \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass and the relevant packages. (See: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228))  It might also be helpful to know the rest f the error message (wich control sequence is undefined?)

Comment: I get no error provided I load the packages `tabularx`, `ragged2e` and `booktabs`.

Comment: Your MWE misses the package `ragged2e`. Without it the command `\RaggedRight` is undefined.

Comment: @egreg you are right. It's my first time using tables and I thought, that the belong to the package `\tabularx`. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My code misses the package `ragged2e`. Without it the command `\RaggedRight` is undefined.